# SwiftUI - remove space between TabView that has PageViewStyle

Tags: swiftui, tabview, pageviews

I have a `TabView` with `7` pages. Each one of the pages has 100 points less than the screen's width.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { reader in
            VStack(alignment: .center) {
                TabView {
                    ForEach(0..<7) { index in
                        VStack {
                            
                        }
                        .frame( maxHeight: .infinity)
                        .frame(width: reader.size.width - 100)
                        .background(Color.red)
                        .cornerRadius(15)
                    }
                }
                .background(Color.yellow)
                .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .always))
                .frame(width: reader.size.width, height: 500)
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        }
        
    }
}
```

`TabView` has as much as much width as the screen's width.

There are 50 points on both sides the Vstack's though each one of them has 100 points less than the screen width.

[image]

I need to remove the space between the red views.

[image]

Comment: can you explain a bit more about your question. What does "I need to have them attached. How to do so?" mean?

Comment: @workingdog I need to remove the space between the pages. Now, there are approximately 100 points padding between them. I don't want to have padding.

Comment: well, just remove the "-100" from the frame. Or use `.frame(width: reader.size.width - 100, height: 500)`

Comment: @workingdog I had tried that. In that case, the two adjacent pages are not visible because the TabView and its content have the same width.

Answer (score 3):

how about something different using a "ScrollView" and a "HStack", like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { reader in
            ScrollView (.horizontal) {
                HStack (spacing: 0) {
                    ForEach(0..<7) { index in
                        VStack {
                            Text("\(index)")
                        }
                        .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
                        .frame(minWidth: reader.size.width - 100)
                        .background(Color.red)
                        .cornerRadius(20)
                    }
                }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 500)
            }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT2: using paging

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { reader in
            VStack(alignment: .center) {
                TabView {
                    ForEach(0..<7) { index in
                        VStack {
                            Text("\(index)")
                        }
                        .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
                        .frame(width: reader.size.width)
                        .background(Color.red)
                        .cornerRadius(25)
                    }
                }
                .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .always))
                .frame(width: reader.size.width, height: 500)
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to have paging enabled. Therefore, I am using TabView with PageViewStyle.

Comment: I've updated my answer. The edit shows one page at a time. You are saying this is not what you want? You want more than one "card" on one page? My test show exactly what your second picture shows.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine Yeah, the goal is to have multiple `TabView` elements visible at the same time

Comment: I need to display the current element left aligned and display the next element partially - with paging behaviour - how to achieve that?